# How to run JUnit tests with Mill

Tags: scala, junit, mill

I have some JUnit tests I want to run.

In `sbt` all I have to do is adding this dependency:

`"com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"`

According to the [Mill documentation](https://www.lihaoyi.com/mill/page/configuring-mill.html#custom-test-frameworks) you have to add the custom framework like:

`def testFrameworks = Seq("org.scalatest.tools.Framework", "WHAT GOES HERE?")`

What do I have to do that my JUnit Tests work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing the question I figured it out:

In `build.sh` you have:

- To add this test dependency:
  `ivy"com.novocode:junit-interface:0.11"`
- to add this test framework:
  `com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework`

The whole component looks then:

```
object myModule extends ScalaModule {
  def scalaVersion = "2.12.8"
  object test extends Tests {
    override def ivyDeps = Agg(
      ivy"org.scalatest::scalatest:3.0.5",
      ivy"com.novocode:junit-interface:0.11"
    )

    def testFrameworks = Seq("org.scalatest.tools.Framework", 
         "com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework")
  }
}
```